# How to find the limit $ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0) }\frac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|} $?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

How to find this limit? $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|} $$

I considered approaching along the sequence $\{(1/n,0)\}$; then the limit is $1$.

Comment: @Fundamental thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write 
$$
\frac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|} = 
\frac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|} \cdot \frac{x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|}{|x|+|3y|}
$$
where the first factor tends to $1$ by the familiar property of sine function. The second factor is 
$$
 1+ \frac{x^2 }{|x|+|3y|} + \frac{9y^2 }{|x|+|3y|}
$$
where 
$$
0\le \frac{x^2 }{|x|+|3y|} \le \frac{x^2 }{|x| } = |x|$$
and similarly for the other term.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is always $1$. Use that near $0$ the function $\sin$ is increasing, so for small $x$ and $y$ we have $\dfrac{\sin(|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|}\le \dfrac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|}$. Also given any small positive $p$ consider $|x|<p$ and $|3y|<p$, then $\dfrac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|}\le\dfrac{\sin(p|x|+p|3y|+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|}= \dfrac{\sin((p+1)(|x|+|3y|))}{|x|+|3y|}$. Now let $t=|x|+|3y|$ and use that $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$ and $\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin((p+1)t)}{t}=p+1$.
Finally let $p\to0$ to conclude that $\lim_{x\to0,y\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x^2+9y^2+|x|+|3y|)}{|x|+|3y|}=1$